# Does building a Windows Visual Studio Xamarin.IOS class library create an Xcode project on the paired MacBook?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to interface a Swift (or Objective-C) user interface Xcode project on the MacBook that calls the Xamarin.IOS class library.

Comment: No it does not.  Try looking at Embeddinator 4000 - https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not create an XCode project on the Macbook that you can edit in Swift. It only uses the Mac to compile the code. You have to

- Install [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) on the Mac computer
- Transfer your directory to the mac and Open the same SLN file in Visual Studio for Mac

Most Xamarin developers actually just use Mac computers for development purposes.